# Prevent string array from being reformatted to scientific

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a macro that takes a column of cells with a list of standards delimited by a " " and adds them to an array if they are a unique value.  I ask the user where they would like to put the array that was created and then paste it at the specified location.

The problem - almost all of the standards start with "1E" and whenever the array is pasted into the sheet, any values that don't have a letter at the end are converted into scientific notation.  I can't format them as text afterward because it destroys the original value.  For example "1E0011" in the array is pasted as "1.00E+11".  If I format this as text (after it has been pasted), it reads "1E+11".  The array is Dim'd as a string.

```
Sub Remove_1E_Duplicates()
'Looks at every "1E" standard in a column and puts every unique value in an array at a user-selected destination

Dim CurrentCell As String               'Used to temporarily store active cell's values
Dim strArray() As String                'Final string with only unique values
Dim tempArray() As String               'Temp array created by splitting CurrentCell's values
Dim i As Integer                        'Counter used for each value in tempArray
Dim elem As Integer                     'Counter for each element in strArray
Dim lLoop As Long, lLoop2 As Long       'Counter for sorted array (ex: if lLoop=5, each element 0-4 is already sorted and 5+ needs to be sorted)
Dim str1 As String, str2 As String      'Place holder for switching two elements' positions in an array when one has a lower sorted value
Dim rListPaste As Range                 'Stores location of the user-input destination

ReDim Preserve strArray(0)

Do While ActiveCell <> vbnullvalue

    If ActiveCell.Value = "Access Denied" Then
        GoTo Denied
    End If

    CurrentCell = ActiveCell.Value
    tempArray = Split(CurrentCell, " ")

    For i = LBound(tempArray) To UBound(tempArray)

        For elem = LBound(strArray) To UBound(strArray)
            'Used if strArray is empty
            If strArray(elem) = "" Then
                strArray(elem) = tempArray(i)
                GoTo NextTemp

            'If the current element in tempArray is already in strArray, go to next element in tempArray
            ElseIf InStr(tempArray(i), strArray(elem)) Then
                GoTo NextTemp

            'If all the elements in strArray have been searched and the element in tempArray is longer than 2 characters, _
            'then resize strArray and add the current tempArray element to strArray (after trimming extra spaces and returns)
            ElseIf elem = UBound(strArray) And Len(tempArray(i)) > 2 And tempArray(i) <> Chr(13) Then
                ReDim Preserve strArray(LBound(strArray) To UBound(strArray) + 1) As String
                strArray(UBound(strArray)) = Replace(Trim(tempArray(i)), vbLf, "")
            End If

        Next elem

NextTemp:       'Goes to next element in tempArray
    Next i

Denied:         'After both arrays have been compared, goto next cell below current active cell
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

Loop

'This loop sorts the strArray array
For lLoop = 0 To UBound(strArray)

    For lLoop2 = lLoop To UBound(strArray)

         If UCase(strArray(lLoop2)) < UCase(strArray(lLoop)) Then
             str1 = strArray(lLoop)
             str2 = strArray(lLoop2)
             strArray(lLoop) = str2
             strArray(lLoop2) = str1
         End If

    Next lLoop2

Next lLoop

Set rListPaste = Application.InputBox _
    (prompt:="Please select destination cell", Type:=8)

i = UBound(strArray) + 1
Range(rListPaste, rListPaste.Offset(i)).Value2 = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(strArray)

End Sub
```

Comment: these are not numbers so why can they not be formatted as strings? also can you use the apostrophe as the initial character?

Comment: Please share the code you are working with. This will help get a better answer for the issue you are seeing. For example, it's important to know how the macro is separating the data.

Comment: Prepend each of the values with `'`

Comment: Code posted.  How would I prepend the apostrophe? Something like:    "'" & tempArray(i)  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of prepending each value with `'`, I ended up formatting the destination range for text *before* putting the array into the destination range instead of afterwards.  I used `Range(rListPaste, rListPaste.Offset(lLoop - 1)).NumberFormat = "@"`. This will eleminate the need for another looped step.  Thank you for the help!